# ping batch file with condition

Tags: batch-file, ping

I'm looking to create a continous ping batch file that will:

1. Prompt for a server. I figured this out already.
2. If alive - will stop pinging and will inform the time it was successful.
3. If unreachable will continue to ping.

Appreciate it!

Comment: For Windows, you can do this using a loop that runs ping once and parse the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this should do the trick.

```
@echo off
:start
Echo Enter Server IP:
set /p ip=

:ping
ping %ip% -n 1 -w 2000 || goto pingFail
echo Ping was Successful to %ip% at %date% %time%
Choice /m "Ping Another Server?"
if %ERRORLEVEL%==2 GOTO :EOF
cls
goto start
:pingFail
Echo Ping failed...Retrying...
goto ping
```